# Pivot spark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

For a dataframe:

```
id,col 
63975914,acacia
63975911,better 
65475384,acacia 
65475385,excelsa
```

I want to pivot the dataframe so that it looks like this:

```
col, value
acacia, 63975914,65475384
better, 63975911
excelsa, 65475385
```

How to do this with PySpark?

Answer (score 0):

Use `collect_set()` and `concat_ws()`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy("col").agg(F.concat_ws(",", F.collect_set("id")).alias('value')).show()
+-------+-----------------+
|    col|            value|
+-------+-----------------+
| acacia|63975914,65475384|
| better|         63975911|
|excelsa|         65475385|
+-------+-----------------+
```